# Go: Decoding only one XML node at a time

Tags: xml, go

Looking through the sourcecode for encoding/xml package, all of the unmarshaling logic (which decodes the actual XML nodes and types them) is in unmarshal and the only way to invoke this is essentially by calling DecodeElement. However, the unmarshaling logic also inherently searches-out the next EndElement. The predominant reason for this seems to be validation. However, this seems to represent a major design flaw to me: What if I have a massive XML file, I am sufficiently confident in its structure, and I'd just like to decode a single node at a time so that I can efficiently filter through the data on-the-fly? The RawToken() call can be used to get the current tag, which is great, but, obviously, when you call DecodeElement() on it, there's an error when the inevitable unmarshal() call apparently starts running into nodes in a way that it perceives as unbalanced.

It seems theoretically possible to encounter a token that I'd like to decode, capture the offset, decode the element, seek back to the previous position, and loop, but that'd still result in a massive amount of unnecessary processing.

Is there no way to just parse one node at a time?

Comment: [Parsing Huge XML Files With Go](http://blog.davidsingleton.org/parsing-huge-xml-files-with-go/) may be of interest.

Comment: I'm aware of it, but it's using the functionality that I'm questioning. It always consumes everything enclosed within the node that you decode, thereby either returning all of it or skipping all of it. In either case, it traverses all of it and I want to avoid having to either do that unnecessarily or having to have to constantly seek back to the next child.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is called XML stream parsing as it is done by any SAX parser, for example. Good news: `encoding/xml` supports that, albeit it is a *bit* hidden.

What you actually have to do is to create an instance of `xml.Decoder`, passing an `io.Reader`. Then you will use `Decoder.Token()` to read the input stream until the next **valid** xml token found. From there, you can decide what to do next.

Here is a little example [also available as gist](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/1da54ebfacaaad54853a), or you can <kbd>[Run it on PlayGround](http://play.golang.org/p/_Fg1zdC-J_)</kbd>:

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    book = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
  <preface>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</preface>
  <chapter num="1" title="Foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</chapter>
  <chapter num="2" title="Bar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</chapter>
</book>`
)

type Chapter struct {
    Num     int    `xml:"num,attr"`
    Title   string `xml:"title,attr"`
    Content string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {

    // We emulate a file or network stream
    b := bytes.NewBufferString(book)

    // And set up a decoder
    d := xml.NewDecoder(b)

    for {

        // We look for the next token
        // Note that this only reads until the next positively identified
        // XML token in the stream
        t, err := d.Token()

        if err != nil  {
            break
        }

        switch et := t.(type) {

        case xml.StartElement:
            // We now have to inspect wether we are interested in the element
            // otherwise we will advance
            if et.Name.Local == "chapter" {
                // Most often/likely element first

                c := &Chapter{}

                // We decode the element into(automagically advancing the stream)
                // If no matching token is found, there will be an error
                // Note the search only happens within the parent.
                if err := d.DecodeElement(&c, &et); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }

                // We have found what we are interested in, so we print it
                fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", c.Num, c.Title)

            } else if et.Name.Local == "book" {
                fmt.Println("Book begins!")
            }

        case xml.EndElement:

            if et.Name.Local != "book" {
                continue
            }

            fmt.Println("Finished processing book!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The principal difference being that I'm providing a Buffer rather than a File?

Comment: The principal difference is that you do not use `xml.Unmarshal()`, but `xml.Decoder.Token()` and `xml.Decoder.DecodeElement()`. So that for the stream part.The `xml.Decoder.DecodeElement()`method actually identifies if an end tag of a non-sub element is found. Simply remove a `</chapter>` on the playground, and you will see. Can the remainder be quite big? Yes. But you leverage that by doing stream parsing, in which the xml read so far is not held in RAM, and you limit what is kept in RAM to the parent element of the unclosed tag. It doesn't get any better.

Comment: Yeah, but DecodeElement actually calls the unmarshal and the unmarshal traverses all of the way to the matching closing tag. I know that it's not in memory, but it's also wasteful to read more than the current tag (I want to process one tag at a time rather than having to seek back constantly). Am I missing something in your explanation?

Comment: So how would you be able to process a tag unless it is read? you could read byte-wise. What you miss is that `Decoder.unmarshal` actually notices a runaway tag – it loads at most until the __parent__ is closed. As you can see in the playground example the parser exactly does what you want: each `<chapter>`is parsed individually.

Comment: I mean that DecodeElement will not only parse through the current tag but then skip everything between the current tag and its closing tag. So, if I want to get the information from the current tag, I'll not be able to get the information for any of the children. It seems like there's a limited amount of flexibility in the built-in encoding/xml package. I can't just use it as a tag-by-tag tokenizer.

Comment: Yes, you can: recursion. Or you can unmashal the _current_ tag and iterate.